# Swift2 OS X use of seekToFileOffset

Tags: macos, swift2, streaming

I am opening a "binary" file for reading as seen below (readD is my function to read a Double from a stream).  The opening and reading are fine, but because the data structure is complex, I need to jump around inside the file.  However, when using the "seekToFileOffset()" method the **file pointer does not seem to change**, so the second readD retrieves the wrong value for av.  I suspect the problem is something simple, but I cannot figure it out.

func readResultsData(fileName: NSURL) -> Bool {

```
let iStream = NSInputStream(URL: fileName)
var fHandle = NSFileHandle()

do {
  fHandle = try NSFileHandle(forReadingFromURL: fileName)
}
catch {
  return false
}

iStream!.open()

do {

  var av = try readD(iStream!)

  fHandle.seekToFileOffset(8)
  let offsetInFile = fHandle.offsetInFile
  Swift.print("File offset = \(offsetInFile)")

  av = try readD(iStream!)  // here, av is not read correctly
```

// and so on...

```
}
catch {
  iStream!.close()
  return false
}

iStream!.close()
return true
```

}

Do I need to open the file as something other than a stream to allow random access in the file?  If so then why does this work correctly:

```
 var fHandle = NSFileHandle()
 let sizeOfFile = fHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
 Swift.print("File size = \(sizeOfFile)")
```

Comment: oddly the docs say that only reading some or all of the data is available. It doesn't mention the positioning option.

Comment: @johnelemans I just read a document from Apple saying that it is recommended to read from files sequentially, so to solve the problem I just extract the information from one layer, close & reopen the file, extract the next layer, and so on until it's done.  I don't know if it's the best solution but it works.